# Cannot create an instance of UserControl in design view, works in Release mode and at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I have a user control `LoadingIndicatorControl` which is displayed in various other controls when loading is happened.

This user control is very simple and looks like this:

```xml
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Visibility="{Binding Loading, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Vis}}">
    <Image x:Name="imgLoadingSpinner"
           gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/Loading_Spinner.gif"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Width="30"
           Height="30" />
</StackPanel>
```

I nest it in other views like this:

```xml
<uc:LoadingIndicatorControl Loading="{Binding Loading}"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
```

When I run this application it compiles without issues and the loading indicator is displayed as I expect.

However at design time only I'm getting errors about this user control, related to the image resource. This gif is set to Build Action `Resource`.

In my host view I get this:

[image: design view error]

And if I look at the detail of why, it says `Cannot locate resource 'images/loading_spinner.gif'`:

[image: cannot locate resource error]

If I look at `LoadingIndicatorControl` in design view it does in fact locate the `loading_spinner.gif` resource and gives no errors.

What I have tried:

- Clean and rebuild numerous times
- Close VS2019 and reopen
- Clean, close VS, reopen and rebuild
- Set `Loading_Spinner.gif` Build Action to `Embedded Resource` (was `Resource` which also works at runtime)
- Tried platform targets `Any CPU`, `x64`, `x86`

Interestingly, setting to build configuration to `Release` does prevent the error from appearing! It only appears when `Debug` is used.

I'm using Visual Studio Professional v16.11.16.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: What is the library you use to display the gif ?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif but I don't believe this is the problem (see my answer). It does correctly display the gif when I view the user control in design view, it was only when said user control was nested inside another) that the design view didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the direct path to the image:

```xml
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Images/Loading_Spinner.gif"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Width="30"
       Height="30" />
```

If you really need the `pack` URI, the format is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), it look like this:

```xml
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="pack://application:,,,/SO_72648958;component/Images/Loading_Spinner.gif"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Width="30"
       Height="30" />
```

Working demo [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_72648958).

Comment: Direct path didn't work for me. Adding `component` into the pack URI results in an exception: `NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.`.

Comment: That's not a normal behavior, you have broken something. Maybe the [AssemblyInfo.cs](https://github.com/Orace/SO/blob/main/SO_72648958/AssemblyInfo.cs) file?

Comment: `Assembly.cs` looks fine... It's got a few more bits in than your example, but it's all just stuff that's set in `Properties -> Application -> Assembly Information`.